# DRM free book shop

Tags: drm

I have just started to explore book market for English literature. I found that all of the big sellers use DRM. It's extremely inconvenient for me, as I have gotten used to the DRM-free Russian Ebook site (litres).

Is there a DRM-free bookshop with a reasonable stock of English books?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[imore.com](https://www.imore.com/best-sites-finding-drm-free-digital-books) suggests:

- [Lulu](http://www.lulu.com/shop)
- [Smashwords](https://www.smashwords.com/)
- [Leanpub](https://leanpub.com/bookstore)

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, they provide a rather limited number of titles... Probably, current dreaded state of the English-language book market is a fact of life. DRM is everywhere and that's all. I still have trouble to get used that  people value freedom and ignore DRM existence at the same time...

Comment: I agree, it is maddening.  I think Amazon's market dominance, plus the commitment of the biggest NY publishers to favor DRM solutions discourages people from selling in alternate channels.

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin smashwords has almost half a million books. I am not sure how that is a limited number of titles.

Answer (score 5):

There are actually lots of sources for books that are DRM-free.

Some provide free books (i.e. books that you do not have to pay for),
and others are just publishers who choose to sell books without DRM,
and trust you for not giving away copies, since they need to sell the
books to make a living. It may also be authors who sell or
give their books directly on the Internet.

For example, many retailers like Kobo, [Smashwords](https://www.smashwords.com) or Amazon have most
books for sale, but also have books available for free.  Both kinds may
be with or without DRM. Amazon uses private standards which, though
not DRM stricto-sensu, may be very inconvenient for some users (such
as myself, using Linux and Android) unless you run Windows or a Mac.

**Where to look depends very much on the kind of books you are looking
for**. For example, I am interested in science fiction in English and
classical literature in French.

Sites I would recommend for a start are [Project Gutenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Gutenberg) and [Internet
Archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Archive) (see sites: [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/) - [Internet
Archive](https://archive.org/))

Macmillan is a major publisher who sells a lot of books
without DRM. A lot of smaller publishers do that too (such as [Baen](https://www.baen.com),
[Phoenix Pick](http://www.phoenixpick.com/), [Wildside Press](http://wildsidepress.com/) and others in Science Fiction and
Fantasy). Most occasionally give books away for free.

Book bundles sellers, such as [HumbleBundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/) and [StoryBundle](https://storybundle.com/space), sell bundles of books that are usually DRM-free (in several years I encountered only one bundle that was under some kind of DRM control, and the seller actually accepted to reimburse me with no fuss).  These can be very interesting sources of good books that are otherwise sold only with DRM. And they are usually rather cheap, compared to their standard price.

Most books in the public domain can be found for free and/or without DRM if you look hard
enough.

Note that when books have no hard DRM (the kind that may be bothering
you), they may still have [watermarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_watermarking), i.e. unique identifiable
characteristics, so that the origin can be traced when those books are
not supposed to be redistributed by the purchaser.

Answer (score 4):

Ebooks.com has plenty in their [DRM-free section](https://www.ebooks.com/drm-free). You can also filter your searches by DRM-free content.

Answer (score 3):

[Baen Books](https://www.baen.com/) and [Tor](https://www.tor.com/) publish without DRM.

Comment: In addition, [Baen Books has a Free Library](https://www.baen.com/allbooks/category/index/id/2012?page=1&pageSize=30&filter=name&dir=ASC), which is a selection of their books for free.

Comment: Tor is very interesting for me. Are they have own book shop or there is some kind of proxy-shop? If so, which one?

Comment: The publisher Tor? They do not have their own ebook store. See https://www.ebooks.com/

Comment: The point is the publisher says whether a book has DRM not the platform. So TOR etc books are Drm free on amazon on kobo or where else they are sold

Answer (score 0):

I think you have  the wrong way of looking at this. The ebook store does not directly decide if a book is DRM protected. The choice of DRM or not is up to the publisher.

So find good publishers and use whatever ebook store is most convenient.

Comment: Things a a bit more complicated. Sone publishers will produce books they sell DRM free. These books may be found in web stores available only with DRM. The reason is that the store does not want to sell DRM free books, and the publisher does not want to lose a reseller. This is just pressure on publishers by the stores.  But it could also be that other publishers put pressure on the store not to sell any DRM-free book. Everything is possible. From (failing) memory, I think books from Wilside Press that they sell DRM-free are found with DRM on some sites.

Comment: @babou which stores force Drm? Tor and Baen at least do take a dim view of this

Comment: "force DRM" is stronger than what I wrote. Maybe my sentence was too
affirmative, but it was my only explanation. All I know is that I have seen
that at least once, and I think twice (though my memory is not too good). The
fact is that, when I am really interested in a book from an unknown imprint, I
try to check on the web whether the publisher might be selling it directly
without DRM. Many small publishers sell DRM-free books, though many do not.
I know about TOR and Baen, and you can add Phoenix Pick and some others. It seems to be a measure of involvement with the content they sell.

Comment: @babou the issue is that it is the publisher not the ebook store that decides on Drm or not

Comment: Well, actually you are wrong, any decision regarding a book belongs to the
author. But, how comes everyone gets the feeling publishers decide. Maybe
because publishers can exert more pressure, have bigger sticks than authors.
But sometimes a retailer has an even bigger stick. Or some corporations have
more économic power, or more political power, or manage to have unfair laws
voted to their advantage. If you are not extremely cynical, then you never met
these people. This said, some are really nice, devoted to their jobs, to
the books, authors and public. But the system is corrupted.